# Conditional entropy of finite mixture model

Tags: entropy, finite-mixture-model, conditional-entropy

I am trying to understand the conditional entropy of the finite mixture model given in [this](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/2005/AAAI05-127.pdf) paper about regularized EM algorithm.

---

---

On page 3 of the paper: in the finite mixture model, we are given $m$ mixed component densities with mixing coefficients $\alpha_k, k = 1,\dots, m$, i.e., $p(c_k) = \alpha_k$, then

$$p(x \mid \Theta)=\sum_{k=1}^{m} \alpha_{k} p\left(x \mid \theta_{k}\right)$$

where $\Theta=\left(\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{m}, \theta_{1}, \ldots, \theta_{m}\right)$

The category information $C$ associated with the observed $X$ is missing. $C$ takes values taking values in $\{ c_1,\dots,c_m \}$.

Then the conditional entropy is given by

$$H(C \mid X, \Theta) = -\int \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{\alpha_{k} p\left(x \mid \theta_{k}\right)}{p(x \mid \Theta)} \log \left(\frac{\alpha_{k} p\left(x \mid \theta_{k}\right)}{p(x \mid \Theta)}\right) p(x \mid \Theta) d x $$

---

---

The above equation can be simplified to

$$H(C \mid X, \Theta) = -\int {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {{\alpha _k}p\left( {x\mid {\theta _k}} \right)} } \log \left( {\frac{{{\alpha _k}p\left( {x\mid {\theta _k}} \right)}}{{p(x\mid \Theta )}}} \right)dx \tag 3$$

I cannot figure out how that can be derived from the original equation for conditional entropy, which is expressed as

$$\mathrm{H}(Y \mid X)=-\iint p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)}dx dy$$

Substituting $Y$ with $C$ and $X$ with $X,\Theta$, then we get an initial expression of conditional entropy for the finite mixture model

$$\mathrm{H}(C \mid X,\Theta)=-\iiint p(x,\theta, c) \log \frac{p(x,\theta, c)}{p(x,\theta)} dx d\theta dc$$

---

The correct derivation seems to be

$$\mathrm{H}(C \mid X,\Theta)=-\iint p(x,\theta, c) \log \frac{p(x,\theta, c)}{p(x,\theta)} dc dx$$
$$ = -\int \sum_k p(c_k)p(x \mid c_k) \log \left( \frac{p(c_k)p(x \mid c_k)}{\sum_k p(c_k)p(x \mid c_k)} \right) dx =(3)$$